# How to refer to data files in a pkg-config package with the autotools and pkg-config?

Tags: homebrew, autoconf, pkg-config

I'm attempting to create a [Homebrew formula for gtk-mac-integration](https://gist.github.com/brechtm/1cc80809d620b8dc58be). Running make in `bindings/python/gtkosx_application` fails:

```
/usr/local/Cellar/python/2.7.9/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/Resources/Python.app/Contents/MacOS/Python: can't open file '/usr/local/Cellar/gtk-mac-integration/2.0.7/share/pygobject/2.0/codegen/h2def.py': [Errno 2] No such file or directory
make[3]: *** [gtkosx_application.defs] Error 2
```

This is because the Makefile tries to find the `h2def.py` file in the wrong location:

```
gtkosx_application.defs: $(headers)
        $(PYTHON) $(datadir)/pygobject/2.0/codegen/h2def.py $(headers) > $@
```

It is clear to me why this is failing: `$(datadir)` points to the share directory of the package that is to be installed (gkt-mac-integration). Because Homebrew installs all packages into their own prefix (`/usr/local/Cellar/...`), it is not the same for gtk-mac-integration and pygobject.

I know it is possible to find out where the pygobject data directory is located using

```
pkg-config --variable=datadir pygobject-2.0
```

I don't suppose the correct fix is to replace `datadir` in the Makefile with the string above? How should I adjust `configure.ac` and `Makefile.am` to make this work properly?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Query pkg-config variable through autotools](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21664473/query-pkg-config-variable-through-autotools)

Answer (score 0):

Yeah, that sounds like a bug in the build system.

You can use the `inreplace` facility to patch this up.  Insert this after `def install`:

`inreplace %w[bindings/python/gtkmacintegration/Makefile.am
             bindings/python/gtkmacintegration/Makefile.in
             bindings/python/gtkosx_application/Makefile.am
             bindings/python/gtkosx_application/Makefile.in],
          '$(datadir)/pygobject',                                 |
          %x[pkg-config --variable=datadir pygobject-2.0].chomp + '/pygobject'`

(I tried this out.  The formula builds after that.)

You should report this upstream.  They should change their build system to sort this out in their `configure` script.